# PopulateBaseTypes-event not triggered

Tags: c#, events, code-generation, codedom

I have some code that is dynamically created via CodeDOM. What I want to achieve is to set a common base-type for every class that does not already *has* a base-type different from `System.Object`. So I hooked to the `PopulateBaseTypes`-event to set the base-type accordingly. However the event is not triggered - neither when I explicitely call `type.BaseTypes` nor when the code-provider builds the code using `GenerateCodeFromNamespace`. From [MSDN: CodeTypeDeclaration.PopulateBaseTypes Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.codedom.codetypedeclaration.populatebasetypes(v=vs.110).aspx) I read this:

> Occurs when the BaseTypes collection is accessed for the first time.

However I don´t know when this property *is* accessed the first time. Can I use this event for this purpose at all?

```
var code = new CodeNamespace(targetNamespace);

// ...
// generate the type-mappings
// ...

foreach (var type in code.Types.Cast<CodeTypeDeclaration>().Where(x => !x.IsEnum))
{
    type.PopulateBaseTypes += (sender, e) => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    };
    Console.WriteLine(type.BaseTypes);
}
```

Comment: I have feeling you are doing this too late. Isn't `code.Types` already contains *constructed* types (means their `BaseTypes` was already accessed)? All this feels hacky. What are you trying to achieve in first place? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4411349/1997232) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11572531/1997232)?

Comment: Basically I have an xsd-file consisting of some classes that don´t have a base-class specified, where I want them to derive my common base-class. Having said this I´m not doing the one or the other. This is why topic is tagged code-generation, as I want to build the class-hierarchy from the xsd, not just modify the behaviour of some instances.